# Openquery statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I am fairly new to SQL, and I am hoping someone can help me with a problem I'm having.  I haven't been able to find any answers helping me figure out this exact problem.

I have two tables in two SQL Server databases on two different servers that I want to compare using the column ItemID. I want to find records from Table1 that have an ItemID that does not exist in Table2 and insert those into a table variable.  I have the following code:

```
--Create table variable to hold query results 
DECLARE @ItemIDTable TABLE 
  ( 
     [itemid][NVARCHAR](20) NULL 
  ); 

--Query data and insert results into table variable  
INSERT INTO @ItemIDTable 
            ([itemid]) 
SELECT a.[itemid] 
FROM   database1.dbo.table1 a 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   [Database2].[dbo].[table2] 
                   WHERE  a.itemid = [Database2].[dbo].[table2].[itemid]) 
ORDER  BY itemid
```

This works on a test server where the two databases are on the same server, but not in real life where they are on different servers.  I tried the following using OPENQUERY, but I know I haven't got it quite right.

```
--Create table variable to hold query results
DECLARE @ItemIDTable TABLE
    (
    [ItemID][nvarchar](20) NULL
    );

--Query data and insert results into table variable 
INSERT INTO @ItemIDTable
    ([ItemID])
    SELECT a.[ItemID]
    FROM  Database1.dbo.Table1 a 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM OPENQUERY([Server2], SELECT * FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Table2]') 
                      WHERE a.ItemID = [Database2].[dbo].[Table2].[ItemID])
    ORDER BY ItemID
```

I'm pretty sure I need to do something in the WHERE clause, where I have the two databases on two servers, I'm just not quite sure how to structure it.  Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an OPENQUERY that is correlated to an outer query.   You could populate a temp table with the results of an OPENQUERY and do your WHERE NOT EXISTS against the temp table, or you might want to look into [Synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I used your suggestion to populate a temp table with the OPENQUERY results, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Openquery works like this:

```
select * 
from openquery
(LINKED_SERVER_NAME,
'select query goes here'
)
```

Note that the sql portion is single quoted.  That means you might have to quote the quotes if necessary.  For example:

```
select * 
from openquery
(LINKED_SERVER_NAME,
'
select SomeTextField
from SomeTable
where SomeDateField = ''20141014''
'
)
```